# Amplify `authState` stays `unauthenticated` after successful login - need to force-refresh useAuthenticator authState [React]

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, custom-authentication, authenticator

I am using Amplify auth to handle authentication. However, after I do the `Auth.signIn()` and `Auth.confirmSignIn()` (for the user to enter the 6-digit code),

the value returned from the hook  `useAuthenticator` for `authStatus` is `'unauthenticated'` and for `route` is still `'signIn'`...

I "fixed" this by just calling `window.location.reload()` in the promise resolve after `Auth.confirmSignIn()`, but it just feels wrong... and there should be a better way to notify Amplify that we have successfully signed in.

The question:
How do I refresh the auth state so that the `useAuthenticator` picks up on my successful (custom) sign in?

#### Code, if needed - below

Main parts of the SignIn component:

```
import { Amplify, Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import { CognitoUser } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
// other imports, component definition and local state...

const onSubmit = () => {
    Auth.signIn({
      username: state.username,
      password: state.password,
    })
      .then((response: CognitoUser) => {
        // if needed, do something custom with the response...
        // if we have a `customChallenge`
        if (resp.challengeName) {
          // navigate to ConfirmSignIn component which renders the form to enter authentication code (from SMS or the Authenticator app)
        }
      }
};
// component render() with username and password inputs and submit button...
```

Main parts of the ConfirmSignIn component:

```
import { useAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import { CognitoUser } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
// other imports, component definition and local state...

const onSubmit = useCallback(
    async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setLoading(true);
      await Auth.confirmSignIn(user, code, AmplifyChallengeName.SMS)
        .then(async csi_data => {
          // calling this doesn't work... doesn't refresh the `useAuthenticator` return values
          const cognitoUser: CognitoUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({ bypassCache: true });
          const currentSession = await Auth.currentSession();

          // calling this doesn't work either...
          cognitoUser.refreshSession(currentSession.getRefreshToken(), (err, session) => {
            const { idToken, refreshToken, accessToken } = session;
          });

          // calling this works... but feels wrong
          // window.location.reload();
        });
      }

// component render() with code input and submit button...
```

and here's the Login component which has the `<Authenticator>`:

```
import { Authenticator, AuthenticatorProps, useAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import AuthenticatorWrapper from "./AuthenticatorWrapper";
// other imports

const customizedAuthRoutes = ["signIn", "confirmResetPassword"]; //

// component definition...

  const renderCustomizedRoute = useCallback(() => {
    switch (route) {
      case "signIn":
        return <SignIn />;

      case "confirmResetPassword":
      default:
        return (
          <ConfirmResetPassword />
        );
    }
  }, [route]);

  return (
    <AuthenticatorWrapper>
      {customizedAuthRoutes.includes(route) ? (
        renderCustomizedRoute()
      ) : (
        <Authenticator
          services={services}
          className="Login"
          hideSignUp
          components={components}
          formFields={formFields}
        >
          {children}
        </Authenticator>
      )}
    </AuthenticatorWrapper>
  );
```

Authenticator Wrapper:

```
export default function AuthenticatorWrapper({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
  const { authStatus } = useAuthenticator(context => [context.authStatus]);

  if (authStatus === "unauthenticated") {
    return (
      <div className="LogoContentCopyrightLayout">
        <Logo className="LoginLogo" />
        {children}
        <Copyright />
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

Comment: Which version of `@aws-amplify/ui-react` are you on? `@aws-amplify/ui-react@4.6.2` rolled out a fix that would keep `authStatus` up to date with the actual auth status. That being said, answer from VonC is spot on and it is generally recommended to keep Amplify UI and Amplify JS Auth logic separated.

Comment: Oh, wow. It would keep the authStatus up to date even if we use Auth.signIn, like i did?
I don't know since I don't have access to this code anymore as I have been moved to another project (not because i couldn't solve this lol).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `SignIn` component, you are using the `Auth.signIn()` method from AWS Amplify to manually sign in the user.
Then, in your `ConfirmSignIn` component, you are using the `Auth.confirmSignIn()` method to manually confirm the sign in.
So you're using the `Auth` methods to manually handle the sign in process.

However, in your AuthenticatorWrapper, you are using the `useAuthenticator` hook from AWS Amplify UI to get the authentication status.

In other words, you are using the [`useAuthenticator` hook](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/advanced) *and* the AWS Amplify Auth methods together.

The `useAuthenticator` hook is intended to be used with the `Authenticator` component to manage state and UI, while the AWS Amplify Auth methods like [`signIn`](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js/#sign-in) and [`confirmSignIn`](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/confirmsignin.html) are typically used separately to handle authentication manually.

In your situation, you are mixing these two approaches. You are manually handling the sign-in process using the Auth methods, but you are relying on the `useAuthenticator` hook to update your application's state.
The problem is that the `useAuthenticator` hook is not aware of the changes to the user's authentication status when you manually sign in the user, which is why the `authStatus` remains `'unauthenticated'`.

---

A better approach would be to rely entirely on the `Authenticator` component and `useAuthenticator` hook, or to handle the authentication process manually and manage the application state yourself. The first approach is simpler and requires less code, while the second approach offers more flexibility and control.

Here is an example of how you can modify your sign-in process to use the `Authenticator` component and `useAuthenticator` hook:

SignIn Component:

```
import { SignIn } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";

const MySignIn = () => {
  return <SignIn />;
};

export default MySignIn;
```

ConfirmSignIn Component:

```
import { ConfirmSignIn } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";

const MyConfirmSignIn = () => {
  return <ConfirmSignIn />;
};

export default MyConfirmSignIn;
```

Login Component:

```
import { Authenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import { useState } from "react";
import MySignIn from "./MySignIn";
import MyConfirmSignIn from "./MyConfirmSignIn";

const MyLogin = () => {
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState();
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  return (
    <Authenticator
      onAuthStateChange={(nextAuthState, authData) => {
        setAuthState(nextAuthState);
        setUser(authData);
      }}
    >
      {authState === "signIn" && <MySignIn />}
      {authState === "confirmSignIn" && <MyConfirmSignIn />}
    </Authenticator>
  );
};

export default MyLogin;
```

Here, the `Authenticator` component automatically handles the sign-in process, and the `onAuthStateChange` prop is used to update the application's state when the user's authentication status changes.

Meaning: This code will render the `MySignIn` component when the `authState` is `'signIn'`, and the `MyConfirmSignIn` component when the `authState` is `'confirmSignIn'`.
The `onAuthStateChange` prop of the `Authenticator` component will automatically update the `authState` and `user` when the authentication status changes.

This way, you will not need to use `Auth.signIn()` or `Auth.confirmSignIn()` methods manually. The `Authenticator` component will handle all the authentication flow for you.

If you prefer to continue handling the authentication process manually, you will need to manage the application state yourself. This could involve creating a context or a Redux store to manage the user's authentication status, and updating this state whenever the user signs in or out.

Comment: First of all, Thank You!

Yeah... I was optimistically mixing two separate tools :/

I am just a bit confused by the 2nd part of your answer, where you created MySignIn and MyConfirmSignIn, but in the Login Component, you imported SignIn and ConfirmSignIn from  "@aws-amplify/ui-react".
Did you want to import MySignIn and MyConfirmSignIn?

Thanks again!

Comment: @FilipSavic True: in the Login Component, I should have imported `MySignIn` and `MyConfirmSignIn` instead of `SignIn` and `ConfirmSignIn` from `@aws-amplify/ui-react`. I have edited the code in the answer accordingly.

Comment: OK, thank you once more :D 
I'll assign the bounty to you as soon as the platform lets me (less than 1hr).